# Manipulate an Object Value and generate a new Object

Tags: javascript

I have an Object that as an ID as key and Array of Objects as Value, I need to generate an Object from this

**The Array**

```
var bears = { 
 "1" :
    [ 
        { 'total_bears': 2, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'CA' },
        { 'bear_age': 100, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'CA' },
        { 'total_bears': 1, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'NM' },
        { 'bear_age': 10, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'NM' }
    ],
 "2" :
    [ 
        { 'total_bears': 1, 'bear_id': 2, 'location': 'CA' },
        { 'bear_age': 50, 'bear_id': 2, 'location': 'CA' } 
    ]
  };
```

**The Result**

```
{ 'bear_id' : 1, 'locationCAtotal_bears' : 2, 'locationCAbear_age': 100, 'locationNMtotal_bears': 1, 'locationNMbear_age':  100}

{ 'bear_id' : 2, 'locationCAtotal_bears' : 1, 'locationCAbear_age': 50}
```

**What I have**

```
for (var key in bears) {
  var arr = bears[key];
  var obj = {};
  var new_arr = arr.map(function(item) {
    if (item.location == 'CA') {
        obj.bear_id = item.bear_id;
        obj.locationCAtotal_bears = item.total_bears;
        obj.locationCAbear_age = item.bear_age;
    }
    else if (item.location == 'NM') {
        obj.bear_id = item.bear_id;
        obj.locationNMtotal_bears = item.total_bears;
        obj.locationNMbear_age = item.bear_age;
    }

    return obj
  });
}
```

That's one of the many code I tried. I've tried different stuff on it but still no luck

Comment: Please provide us what you've done till now. Then we'll be able to point out your mistake

Comment: @NafiulIslam I have added the code I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**  and **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** methods

```js
var bears = {
  "1": [{
    'total_bears': 2,
    'bear_id': 1,
    'location': 'CA'
  }, {
    'bear_age': 100,
    'bear_id': 1,
    'location': 'CA'
  }, {
    'total_bears': 1,
    'bear_id': 1,
    'location': 'NM'
  }, {
    'bear_age': 10,
    'bear_id': 1,
    'location': 'NM'
  }],
  "2": [{
    'total_bears': 1,
    'bear_id': 2,
    'location': 'CA'
  }, {
    'bear_age': 50,
    'bear_id': 2,
    'location': 'CA'
  }]
};


var res = Object.keys(bears).map(function(k) {
  return bears[k].reduce(function(obj, ele) {
    Object.keys(ele).forEach(function(key) {
      // set all property except location and bear//-id
      if (key !== 'bear_id' && key !== 'location')
        obj['location' + ele.location + key] = ele[key];
    });
    return obj;
    // pass object with bear_id as initial value
  }, {
    bear_id: bears[k][0].bear_id
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution, while iterating a map, the object (item.total_bears)value is  undefined, you check a if condition like this.

```
var bears = { 
 "1" :
    [ 
    { 'total_bears': 2, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'CA' },
    { 'bear_age': 100, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'CA' },
    { 'total_bears': 1, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'NM' },
    { 'bear_age': 10, 'bear_id': 1, 'location': 'NM' }
    ],
 "2" :
    [ 
    { 'total_bears': 1, 'bear_id': 2, 'location': 'CA' },
    { 'bear_age': 50, 'bear_id': 2, 'location': 'CA' } 
    ]
  };

var newBears = [];
for (var key in bears) {
  var arr = bears[key];
  var obj = {};
  var new_arr = arr.map(function(item) {

    if (item.location === 'CA') {
    obj.bear_id = item.bear_id;
    if (item.total_bears)
        obj.location_CAtotal_bears = item.total_bears;
    obj.locationCAbear_age = item.bear_age;
    }
    else if (item.location === 'NM') {
    obj.bear_id = item.bear_id;
    if (item.total_bears)
        obj.location_NMtotal_bears = item.total_bears;
    obj.locationNMbear_age = item.bear_age;
    }

    return obj
  });
  newBears.push(obj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newBears));
```

Now the newBears array will have your result.